# How can i simulate the write contract in etherscan using Web3.py?

Tags: etherscan, web3.py

I would like to use web3.py instead of using the etherscan write contract function available in ethercan.io, [image: Etherscan.io write contract function]

Is this possible? if yes can someone please show me a sample. The contract address of the sample above: https://etherscan.io/token/0x2b591e99afe9f32eaa6214f7b7629768c40eeb39#writeContract

Answer (score 2):

"Writing to contracts" is a somewhat confusing term from Etherscan.

It is doing a transaction to a smart contract address and function.

If look [Web3.py examples](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#working-with-contracts) the example that calls the function `setVar()` is writing to the contract.

```py
import sys
import time
import pprint

from web3.providers.eth_tester import EthereumTesterProvider
from web3 import Web3
from solc import compile_source


def compile_source_file(file_path):
   with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
      source = f.read()

   return compile_source(source)


def deploy_contract(w3, contract_interface):
    tx_hash = w3.eth.contract(
        abi=contract_interface['abi'],
        bytecode=contract_interface['bin']).deploy()

    address = w3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)['contractAddress']
    return address


w3 = Web3(EthereumTesterProvider())

contract_source_path = 'contract.sol'
compiled_sol = compile_source_file('contract.sol')

contract_id, contract_interface = compiled_sol.popitem()

address = deploy_contract(w3, contract_interface)
print("Deployed {0} to: {1}\n".format(contract_id, address))

store_var_contract = w3.eth.contract(
   address=address,
   abi=contract_interface['abi'])

gas_estimate = store_var_contract.functions.setVar(255).estimateGas()
print("Gas estimate to transact with setVar: {0}\n".format(gas_estimate))

if gas_estimate < 100000:
  print("Sending transaction to setVar(255)\n")
  tx_hash = store_var_contract.functions.setVar(255).transact()
  receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(tx_hash)
  print("Transaction receipt mined: \n")
  pprint.pprint(dict(receipt))
  print("Was transaction successful? \n")
  pprint.pprint(receipt['status'])
else:
  print("Gas cost exceeds 100000")
```

Comment: thanks for the sample, at first i get this error ImportError: cannot import name 'compile_source' from 'solc'. If i get through this error, would it be possible to give me a hand to actually apply it to my original sample function?

Comment: Yes. You need to compile your smart contracts using `solc`. Based on the outputted ABI files you can construct `web3.Contract` code in Python.